# automate login / scrape files from a website

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, jsoup, scrapy

I need to figure out how to scrape a website and download files from an authenticated website.

A script needs to

1. login to this website using a username/password
2. navigate through the pages to get to the download page
3. set some fields in the form and hit download button
4. save the downloaded file

I have been looking at Jsoup (since Java is my preference), but can also try scrapy etc. But I need to understand if these are commonly done and if there is some other technology to enable this. 
I could set this up using something like Selenium, but I dont want a tool that uses a browser as a UA because of the huge additional overhead. 
I am getting somewhere but the whole cookie management is getting very confusing.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

If you require a lot of interaction with the webpage as you describe there is no way around using a real browser - at least from my experience. Selenium webdriver however works great with phantomjs, so the overhead is not too big.

As pointed out in then comment below you can use something like mechanize as well, however such solutions tend to be usesless when there is javascript that changes the  DOM on the pages. (see http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html#script)

Comment: Not true, any mechanize-like library can do this.

Comment: Well, true. I adapt my answer.

Comment: Not useless at all, you might need to figure out a few ajax calls but in my experience that's preferable to the headaches that accompany selenium.

Comment: I am no advocate for selenium. I use whatever works. maybe I should have chosen less drastic words. in the end the OP got now some hints and can decide what to do.

Comment: Ok. In general though I think it can be said that selenium-like solutions are for unit testing, while mechanize-like solutions are for scraping.

Comment: Thanks all. My issue with using scraping libraries is that you need to decode everything that a site is doing in order to automate. You really need to know what is going on. (Things get very tricky when you have websites doing various oauth kind of flows). Selenium kind of hides all that and I like that part. But I would love a hybrid approach where a selenium like tool shows me exactly whats happening and then I automate it using a library. Comments?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Fiddler2 and navigate through the site as normal.

Once you have done it you should easily be able to replicate the page calls required and anything Javascript may have done with minimal fuss and code.

I tend to use the below to download pages in a number of forms at once and it saves cookies for login sites etc:

```
function Download($href)
   {

        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);   // Cookie management.
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, CURL_TIMEOUT);    // Timeout
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, WEBBOT_NAME);   // Webbot name
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);           // Minimize logs
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    // No certificate
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);     // Follow redirects
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);             // Limit redirections to four
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);     // Return in string
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $href);             // Target site
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $href);            // Referer value
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        # Create return arrays
        $return_array['FILE']   = curl_exec($this->ch); 
        $return_array['STATUS'] = curl_getinfo($this->ch);
        $return_array['ERRORS']  = curl_error($this->ch);
        $dom_document = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom_document->loadHTML($return_array['FILE']);
        $return_array['DOM'] = new DOMXpath($dom_document);


        return $return_array;
   }
```

This is my HttpHelper Class. Easy to make use of and its just Html:

```
<?php
class HttpHelper {


    function __construct() {
    //setcookie("UserPostcode","2065",time() + 3600);
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        define("WEBBOT_NAME", "Test Webbot");
        # Length of time cURL will wait for a response (seconds)
        define("CURL_TIMEOUT", 25);
        # Location of your cookie file. (Must be fully resolved local address)
        define("COOKIE_FILE", "cookie.txt");
        # DEFINE METHOD CONSTANTS
        define("HEAD", "HEAD");
        define("GET",  "GET");
        define("POST", "POST");
        # DEFINE HEADER INCLUSION
        define("EXCL_HEAD", FALSE);
        define("INCL_HEAD", TRUE);


        $header = array();
        $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
        $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
        $header[] =  "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
        $header[] =  "Connection: keep-alive";
        $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
        $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);        // Set Header Information

   }

   // Collects the HTML, Status, Errors and a DOM.
   function Download($href)
   {

        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);   // Cookie management.
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, CURL_TIMEOUT);    // Timeout
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, WEBBOT_NAME);   // Webbot name
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);           // Minimize logs
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    // No certificate
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);     // Follow redirects
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);             // Limit redirections to four
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);     // Return in string
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $href);             // Target site
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $href);            // Referer value
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        # Create return arrays
        $return_array['FILE']   = curl_exec($this->ch); 
        $return_array['STATUS'] = curl_getinfo($this->ch);
        $return_array['ERRORS']  = curl_error($this->ch);
        $dom_document = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom_document->loadHTML($return_array['FILE']);
        $return_array['DOM'] = new DOMXpath($dom_document);


        return $return_array;
   }

   function http_post_form($target, $ref, $data_array)
    {
    return $this->http($target, $ref, $method="POST", $data_array, EXCL_HEAD);
    }

function http_post_withheader($target, $ref, $data_array)
    {
    return http($target, $ref, $method="POST", $data_array, INCL_HEAD);
    }

   function http($target, $ref, $method, $data_array, $incl_head)
    {
    # Initialize PHP/CURL handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    # Prcess data, if presented
    if(is_array($data_array))
        {
        # Convert data array into a query string (ie animal=dog&sport=baseball)
        foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) 
            {
            if(strlen(trim($value))>0)
                $temp_string[] = $key . "=" . urlencode($value);
            else
                $temp_string[] = $key;
            } 
        $query_string = join('&', $temp_string);
        }else{ 
            $query_string =$data_array;
        }

    # HEAD method configuration
    if($method == HEAD)
        {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);                // No http head
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);                // Return body
        }
    else
        {
        # GET method configuration
        if($method == GET)
            {
            if(isset($query_string))
                $target = $target . "?" . $query_string;
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE); 
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE); 
            }
        # POST method configuration
        if($method == POST)
            {
            if(isset($query_string))
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, FALSE); 
            }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $incl_head);   // Include head as needed
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE);        // Return body
        }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);   // Cookie management.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, CURL_TIMEOUT);    // Timeout
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, WEBBOT_NAME);   // Webbot name
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target);             // Target site
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);            // Referer value
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);           // Minimize logs
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    // No certificate
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);     // Follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);             // Limit redirections to four
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);     // Return in string

    # Create return array
    $return_array['FILE']   = curl_exec($ch); 
    $return_array['STATUS'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $return_array['ERROR']  = curl_error($ch);

    # Close PHP/CURL handle
    curl_close($ch);

    # Return results
    return $return_array;
    }

   function InnerHtml($element) 
    { 
        $innerHTML = ""; 
        if($element != NULL && $element->hasChildNodes())
        {
            $children = $element->childNodes; 
            foreach ($children as $child) 
            { 
                $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
                $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true)); 
                $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
            } 
        }
        return $innerHTML; 
    } 


   function Split($data, $split)
   {
        return explode($split, $data);
   }

    function correctImgUrls($html, $url)
    {
        $DOM = new DOMDocument;
        $DOM->loadHTML($html);

        $imgs = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach($imgs as $img){
            $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
            if(strpos($src, $url) !== 0){
                $img->setAttribute('src', $url.$src);
            }
        }

        $html = $DOM->saveHTML();
        return $html;
    }

    function correctUrls($html, $url)
    {
        $DOM = new DOMDocument;
        $DOM->loadHTML($html);

        $imgs = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
        foreach($imgs as $img){
            $src = $img->getAttribute('href');
            if(strpos($src, $url) !== 0){
                $img->setAttribute('a', $url.$src);
            }
        }

        $html = $DOM->saveHTML();
        return $html;
    }

    function removeHref($html)
    {
        $DOM = new DOMDocument;
        $DOM->loadHTML($html);

        $imgs = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
        foreach($imgs as $img){
            $src = $img->getAttribute('href');
            $img->setAttribute('href', "#");
        }

        $html = $DOM->saveHTML();
        return $html;
    }


   function QuerySelector($dom, $xPath)
   {
        return $dom->query($xPath);
   }
   /*
   function __destruct() {
        # Close PHP/CURL handle
        echo "Destruct Called..";
        curl_close($ch);
   }*/


}
?>
```

Simulate your login and do what you need to do: This is an example I use to login to my oDesk account and scrape job postings that I then email to myself :P

```
include("Business/Http/HttpHelper.php");
    $bot = new HttpHelper;
    //$download = $bot ->Download("https://www.odesk.com/login");
    $data['username'] = "myusername";
    $data['password'] = "myPassword";
    $bot -> http_post_form("https://www.odesk.com/login", "https://www.odesk.com/login", $data);
```

You owe me!